# Regex capture IP address and username which are not consistent on all events

Tags: pcre

Following are some logs from ASA, I need to capture following group for IP address, seq number (3327 in this case) and user name (abcd_user.name).

I have tried following regex but the username is capturing with brackets.

https://regex101.com/r/NbyYyp/1

```
Feb 10 13:22:55 90.23.222.10 : %ASA-6-302020: Built inbound ICMP connection for faddr 10.34.27.20/0 gaddr 10.23.24.2/33327 laddr 10.23.24.2/33327    
Feb 10 13:22:51 90.27.29.8 : %ASA-6-302020: Built inbound ICMP connection for faddr 90.23.40.16/1(LOCAL\abcd_user.name) gaddr 172.20.220.27/0 laddr 172.20.20.7/0 (abcd_user.name)    
Feb 10 13:22:55 90.22.22.15 : %ASA-6-302020: Built inbound ICMP connection for faddr 10.34.27.2/0 gaddr 10.34.21.29/33327 laddr 10.34.21.29/33327
```

Your help is much appreciated.

Comment: What is the issue with the current solution?

Comment: user name comes with brackets abcd_user.name :(

Comment: Try https://regex101.com/r/NbyYyp/2

Comment: Its working. thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may use

```
302020: Built inbound.*faddr\s+([^\/]*)\/\d+(.*(gaddr\s+([^\/]+))\/(\d+) laddr([^\/]+)\/\d+)(?:\s*\(([^()]*)\))?
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/NbyYyp/2)

The last `(.*)` capturing group just captured all text to the end of the line. I replaced it with `(?:\s*\(([^()]*)\))?`, an optional non-capturing group that matches 1 or 0 occurrences of

- `\s*` - 0+ whitespaces
- `\(` - a `(` char
- `([^()]*)` - Capturing group: any 0+ chars other than `(` and `)`
- `\)` -  a `)` char.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help

Comment: @spectrum Glad it worked for you. Please also consider upvoting if my answer proved helpful to you.